# Как изменить текст элементов и получить текст веб страницы?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

У меня есть такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

document = soup.html.find_all()

el = []  
for n in document:
    el.append(n.text)
print(el)
```

Он получает текст и выводит его. Но как этот текст изменить на свой и получить в html_doc2 - изменённый текст с разметкой ?

Comment: Неужели в документации ничего об этом не сказано? =)

Comment: Inventor - Я в документации ни нашел. Если использовать метод string то он изменяет содержимое с тегами. А по другому как-то изменять в документации особо не сказано

Comment: А что мешает перед этим сохранить теги в переменную и добавить их снова?

Comment: Inventor - это уже будет костыль

Comment: Костыль это текст на одном уровне с тегами. А так можете сидеть ждать, пока разработчики сделают элегантное решение для вашего костыля)